# Derivation of QFT product formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-computer

If the quantum fourier transform is defined as follows:

$$
U_{FT} |x\rangle = \frac{1}{2^{n/2}} \sum^{2^n-1}_{y=0} e^{2\pi i x y / 2^n} | y \rangle.
$$

We can rewrite the exponential term as:

$$
e^{2\pi i x y / 2^n} = \prod^{n-1}_{l=0}e^{2\pi i x y_l/2^{n-l}}.
$$

Using the binary decomposition of $y$. This next step I don't follow, how do use these to derive this new equation for $U_{FT}$?

$$
U_{FT} |x \rangle = \frac{1}{2^{n/2}} \prod^{n-1}_{l=0} \left( |0\rangle + e^{2\pi i x /2^{n-l}}|1\rangle \right).
$$

Comment: Around here "QFT" usually stands for "Quantum Field Theory." You might want to try this question (and similar questions) at the Quantum Computing Stack Exchange: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @hft Thank-you, I will bare this in mind for future questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By binary decomposition, we define $y\equiv\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} y_l 2^{-l}$, where $|y\rangle=|y_0...y_{n-1}\rangle$.
Putting together your definition of the quantum Fourier transform with this binary decomposition gives
\begin{equation}
U_{FT}|x\rangle=2^{-n/2}\sum_{y=0}^{2^n-1} \prod_{l=0}^{n-1}  e^{2 \pi i x y_l/{2^{n-l}}} |y \rangle=2^{-n/2} \sum_{y_0=0}^{1} ...\sum_{y_{n-1}=0}^1  e^{2 \pi i x y_0/{2^{n}}}...e^{2 \pi i x y_{n-1}/{2^1}} |y_0...y_{n-1} \rangle
\end{equation}

Therefore, we perform our sum over each $y_{l}$ from right to left to end up with:
\begin{equation}
2^{-n/2}(1|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i x /2^n}|1\rangle)...(1|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i x /2^1}|1\rangle)
\end{equation}
which is what we want.

Comment: I fixed the definition of $U_{FT}$ in my question, feel free to update your answer. Thank-you